# took 8 hours to transfer 12 GB

Tags: ssh, vmware, ftp, filezilla

I needed to transfer vmware images of an operating system from one machine to another in my network,it took 8 hours bottom of image you can see time taken,
the connection was done using ssh (encrypted connection was slow) 
is there some way to reduce the time taken, because USB drive I have is maximum 8GB,

![ssh transfer][1]

I tried install vfstpd on machine where I wanted to transfer 
but I gave up when I got following error

```
This FTP server is anonymous only.
Login failed.
```

Not sure what to do.Let me know if there is an easier method which takes less time to transfer file like 12GB in a shorter duration.I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: How are the two machines connected? With consumer-grade hardware  and a regular wired network you should be able to reach transfer speeds of 10MB/s, 20 times faster than what you experienced.

Comment: One is on a wired network and the other machine was on wifi but I thin ssh encryption caused this delay

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python installed, there's a really simple http server that you can run in a directory and then access the files from another computer (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)

```
cd yourdirectory/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and then you can access that directory and its files (plus recursion) by going to that comptuer's ip address elsewhere on the network.  Keep in mind this is un-encrypted so someone else could snoop your traffic if they were on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Distance and obstructions reduce the quality of a wireless link, lowering the available bandwidth. For better results move the machine that's on WiFi closer to the access point, or use a wired connection.

SSH encryption has a minimal overhead and will not cause a significant delay in the transfer. If you use SSH / SFTP you can enable compression, which may make the transfer complete faster because less data has to be sent. There doesn't seem to be a way to enable compression in FileZilla, but you can always use the command line client. To enable compression use the `-C` switch.

```
sftp -C user@remote
```